# SearchManager with special characters

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I'm using SearchManager to search for words in a database. It works fine with standard letters, but when using language specific letters (č,ž,š), it only finds the word if the letter is in the middle of the word. If the letter is in the beggining of the word, it returns that there are no mathes (but they exist in the database). Can the encoding of the SearchManager be changed?